# iTunes Connect - "Submit for Review" Error

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

So the public GM for Xcode7, and ios9 are out. I downloaded them, tested things, and now I am trying to push an update.

This is the error I get in iTunesConnect

```
New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, and iOS 8 SDK or later. 
Don't submit apps built with beta software.
```

Does anyone know what is happening? How do I get past this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed today. You can go ahead and submit apps with ios9 support.

Godspeed!

Answer (score 0):

Now it is not possible to submit applications to AppStore built with iOS 9 SDK and XCode 7.

You need to wait sometime.
It will become available soon.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting iOS 9 apps is not available yet.

Check https://developer.apple.com/news/ for the announcement.